# Maximal Ideal Criteria in a Non-Commutative case

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

**Question:**
Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring with $1\neq 0$. Let $M$ be an ideal(two-sided) of $R$.
 If $\frac{R}{M}$ is a field. Show that $M$ is a maximal ideal.

**My Attempt:**
Suppose that $M$ contains $1$.
 
$\Rightarrow M=R$
$\Rightarrow \frac{R}{M}=(0)$ which is not a Field.

$\Leftarrow$ Contradiction to the fact that $R/M$ is a field.
$\Rightarrow M$ doesn't contain $1$.
$\Rightarrow M \subsetneq R$

Now, Let $J$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $J\subset M\subsetneq R$
Define $\phi:\frac{R}{J}\rightarrow \frac{R}{M}$ by $\phi(r+J)=r+M$
 By Third Isomorphism Theorem (Dummit and Foote, 3rd ed.), We have 
 $\frac{(\frac{R}{J})}{(\frac{M}{J})} \cong \frac{R}{M}$

Given that $\frac{R}{M}$ is a field and $\frac{M}{J}$ is the proper ideal of $\frac{R}{J}$, we have
$\frac{M}{J}=(0)$
$\Rightarrow M=J$
Therefore, $M$ is the maximal ideal of $R$.

*Please Help me to spot my mistake and Give me hints to correct it.*

Comment: One mistake which I can see is that you have considered $J \subset M \subsetneq R$, whereas to show that $M$ is a maximal ideal, you need to show that if $M \subseteq J \subsetneq R$ then, $M=J$. Or maybe it's just  a typo??

Comment: @Rick It's not a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see that for any ring $R$, commutative or not, $R/M$ is a *division ring* only if $M$ is a maximal two-sided ideal, to wit:

If $R/M$ is a *division ring*, then

$a \notin M \Longrightarrow 0 \ne a + M \in R/M \Longrightarrow$
$\exists 0 \ne b + M \in R/M, \; ab + M = (a + M)(b + M) = 1 + M \in R/M; \tag 1$

thus

$\exists m \in M, \; ab + m = 1; \tag 2$

now if $M$ is *not* maximal in the set of two-sided ideals of $R$, there exists a two-sided ideal $J$ such that

$M \subsetneq J \subsetneq R; \tag 3$

let

$a \in J \setminus M; \tag 4$

then by what we have seen we may find $b$ such that

$1 = ab + m \in J, \; m \in M: \tag 5$

since

$a, m \in J; \tag 6$

but $1 \in J$ yields

$r \in R \Longrightarrow r = r \cdot 1 \in J \Longrightarrow J \subset R \Longrightarrow J = R, \tag 7$

in contradiction to (3); therefore no such $J$ can exists and we have $M$ maximal amongst the two-sided ideals of $R$.